# Buscar informações de uma td pelo jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Tenho dentro do meu sistema uma espécie de mesa de analise, onde o cliente irá verificar item por item preenchido de acordo com o que o vistoriador fez. Dentro desta tela há uma seção para o checklist, que é montado dinamicamente no momento o qual o cliente acessa a mesa de analise e de acordo com os itens de checklist.
A estrutura básica da página fica desta forma:

```html
<table> 
<tr>
<td id=X>Trecho1 <input type='text' name='teste' + IDdoChecklistsCliente/> <td>
<td>Trecho2 <select> 
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'> Teste 1</option>
<option value='2'> Teste 2 </option>
<option value='3'> Teste 3</option>
</select> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, trás os dados todos preenchidos de acordo com o banco de dados. Só que não consigo fazer a leitura destes dados (do input e do select). Tentei fazer um each() e buscar as informações da  vem tudo menos os dados do input e do select. Como a montagem da página é feito dinamicamente pegando os itens de checklist do cliente, as IDs do input e select modificam-se a cada cliente.

Como mencionado ai em cima já usei o each para pesquisar as TD conforme o trecho abaixo:

```js
$('table tr').each(function (index, tr) {
        var tds = $(tr).find('td');
        $(tds).each(function (indexTd, td) {
           // alert($(td).text());
            var teste = $(td).text();
            alert(teste);
        });
    });
```

O resultado no alert foi : Trecho1, Trecho2, Teste1Teste2Teste3. Mesmo se tiver algo no textbox ele não informa e muito menos qual a informação da combo.

Alguma solução para isso?

## edição

Para ter uma ideia do que eu quero. Eis uma da parte das informações que eu quero:

[image: Tela de Checklist]

Tenho que pegar cada informação (id do Checklist, valor da Combo, Observação) de cada linha. Tentei atribuir uma ID para a table para que eu pudesse pegar apenas as linhas especificas desta table, mas ela busca todas as informações das telas adicionais, não apenas da table. (Tem a tela de solicitante, veiculo, checklist e fotos do veículo).

O trecho do código especifico para esta parte é esta:

```js
var tabela = document.getElementById("MinhaTabela");
    var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    
    var Textoimput1;
    var Combo;
    var Textoimput2;
    // Preciso percorrer todas as linhas da TR e pegar os valores de cada TD que tenha o input
    
    for (var i = 0; var < linhas.lenght; i ++)
    {
       Textoimput1 = $('input')[i];
        Combo = $('select option:selected')[i];
        Textoimput2 = $('input')[i];
        alert($(Textoimput1).val() + " - " + $(Combo).val() + "- " + $(Textoimput2).val());    
    }
    
    // Mesmo identificando que é para buscar apenas os dados da Table MinhaTabela
    // Está buscando informações de outras telas que compõe esta tela de checklist.
```

```html
<table id= "MinhaTabela">
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='idchecklist' + id[i] value='12345'></td>
<td><label>Nome do Item de Checklist</label></td>
<td><select>
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'>APROVADO </option>
<option value='2'>REPROVADO </option>
<option value='3'>NÃO AVALIADO </option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='Observacaochecklist' + id[i+1] value=' '></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='idchecklist' + id[i] value='54321'></td>
<td><label>Nome do Item de Checklist</label></td>
<td><select>
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'>APROVADO </option>
<option value='2'>REPROVADO </option>
<option value='3'>NÃO AVALIADO </option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='Observacaochecklist' + id[i+2] value=' '></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='idchecklist' + id[i] value='12346'></td>
<td><label>Nome do Item de Checklist</label></td>
<td><select>
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'>APROVADO </option>
<option value='2'>REPROVADO </option>
<option value='3'>NÃO AVALIADO </option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='Observacaochecklist' + id[i] value=' '></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Além de repetir as informações dos inputs, ele está buscando informações das outras telas (Solicitante, Veiculo, Fotos Veículo). Lembrando que infelizmente não tenho como deixar os itens de checklist estáticos (o que facilitaria em 1000000% a minha vida) pois cada cliente tem o seu próprio checklist, então é montado esta table dinamicamente de acordo com as informações do checklist cadastrado no banco de dados.

Comment: Se postar seu codigo pode ser que possamos ajuda-lo. ;o)

Comment: Inseri o trecho do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $ar_tr = $('table[id=MinhaTabela] tr');
    
    $.each($ar_tr, function(i, $tr){
    
      input_idchecklist = $($tr).find('input')[0];
      alert( $(input_idchecklist).attr('name') + ': ' + $(input_idchecklist).val() );
      opcao = $($tr).find('select option:selected');
      alert( $(opcao).val() );
      
      input_observacao = $($tr).find('input')[1];
      alert( $(input_observacao).attr('name') + ': ' + $(input_observacao).val() );
      
    
    });
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id= "MinhaTabela">
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='idchecklist' + id[i] value='12345'></td>
<td><label>Nome do Item de Checklist</label></td>
<td><select>
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'>APROVADO </option>
<option value='2'>REPROVADO </option>
<option value='3'>NÃO AVALIADO </option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='Observacaochecklist' + id[i+1] value=' '></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='idchecklist' + id[i] value='54321'></td>
<td><label>Nome do Item de Checklist</label></td>

<td><select>
<option value='0'> </option>
<option value='1'>APROVADO </option>
<option value='2'>REPROVADO </option>
<option value='3'>NÃO AVALIADO </option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input type='text' name='Observacaochecklist' + id[i+1] value=' '></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="button">Mostrar</button>
```

Comment: Testei aqui mas infelizmente não buscou as informações.

Comment: Ajustei para atender ao codigo fontes mais completo que postou, da uma olhada.

Comment: Cleyton com esta modificação consegui pegar os valores corretamente. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Beleza! Vote em sua resposta preferida para ajudar a comunidade. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Defina uma classe para cada.

Rode uma função map para cada tipo de classe pegando o valor com $(this).val()